# Blocking some of number pad's numbers so that it is adapted to the user input.

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboard, numpad

My app asks the user for a precise number of minutes which she/he inserts using a number pad keyboard. I'd like to block the keyboard's numbers >5 for the first number the user types (so that they can't type a number of minutes > 59). For the second number, I'd like it to unblock the previously blocked numbers so that the minutes can be precisely inserted (e.g. 18 or 59). Is there a way to do this? If so, how?

Comment: You will need to create your own input view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should work with 
[`textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:) from the [`UITextFieldDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/).

Here is a working example of what you can do:

```
 func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        var startString =  NSString()
        if textField.text != nil {
            startString = textField.text! as NSString
        }

        let endString = startString.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

         if endString.isEmpty == true {
            return true
         }


        let intValue = Int(endString)
        if intValue >= 0 && intValue < 60 {
            return true
        }

        return false
    }
```

In this case, it will allow every integer value between 0 (included) and 60 (excluded).

Edit: 
This method is called by the `UITextField` on it's delegate (if you don't understand what is a delegate, take some time to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052926/what-is-the-purpose-of-an-ios-delegate), this pattern is very important).

So, to make the method above works, you just have to say to your `UITextField` that your `UIViewController` is its delegate. You can do it in the code (in `viewDidLoad` for example) or in *Interface Builder*. Here is a fully working example:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField.delegate = self
    }

    func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        var startString = NSString()
        if textField.text != nil {
            startString = textField.text! as NSString
        }

        let endString = startString.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

         if endString.isEmpty == true {
            return true
         }    

        let intValue = Int(endString)
        if intValue >= 0 && intValue < 60 {
            return true
        }

        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I then call this function? I don't really know what I should write. Thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer with informations about the delegation :)

Comment: Cool thanks. Now it doesn't allow any number higher than 59. However, for some reason, it doesn't allow the user to delete the very first number (e.g. the 5 in 53). Why does it do that? And how can it be solved? Btw I think I now understand delegates a bit better. Thanks.

Comment: You just have to check if `endString.length == 0` and return true in this case. I just edited my answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Please, mark this question as solved if it's the case :)